MT7601U Wireless Adapter only works if connected after boot
I'm using a Raspberry Pi Zero W, with a USB hub and adding a second wifi. If the dongle in question is connected after boot, it works flawlessly:
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter

If a reboot is called, lsusb will NOT show the card, and dmesg shows the following error:
usb 1-1-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?

All other USB devices do show up correctly after reboot.
System: 
Linux xxx 6.1.21+ #1642 Mon Apr  3 17:19:14 BST 2023 armv6l GNU/Linux 
Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 
USB 2.0 Hub based on FE1.1S

Why are you using an OS that's at least a year old? Download the latest version and try with that.

This is already deployed in a system, in another continent, updating OS would definitely break something, reinstalling from scratch is a lot of work, lots of dependencies, and the obvious distance.
I’m looking for something more in solving than avoiding the problem, otherwise I can always used another dongle model that I know that works.
Btw, same dongle on a 5 year old OS on a rpi3 works, so OS is not the issue.
Thanks
